# Can I create a CNAME in Route53 pointing to a non-aws host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

[Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/) doc says:

> Amazon Route 53 offers ‘Alias’ records (an Amazon Route 53-specific
>   virtual record). Alias records are used to map resource record sets in
>   your hosted zone **to Amazon Elastic Load Balancing load balancers,
>   Amazon CloudFront distributions, AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments,
>   or Amazon S3 buckets that are configured as websites**. Alias records
>   work like a CNAME record in that you can map one DNS name
>   (example.com) to another ‘target’ DNS name
>   (elb1234.elb.amazonaws.com).

Does this mean I am not able to CNAME to a non-aws host?

[Here's an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/route53/#example_Route53_ChangeResourceRecordSets_shared02) from aws:

```
            Action: aws.String("CREATE"),
            ResourceRecordSet: &route53.ResourceRecordSet{
                AliasTarget: &route53.AliasTarget{
                DNSName:           aws.String("d123rk29d0stfj.cloudfront.net"),
                    EvaluateTargetHealth: aws.Bool(false),
                    HostedZoneId:         aws.String("Z2FDTNDATAQYW2"),
                },
                Name: aws.String("example.com"),
                Type: aws.String("A"),
            },
```

If it is possible to CNAME to a non-aws host, what should I specify in the `ResourceRecordSet`?

Comment: That is a description of "alias" records saying they work *like* a CNAME.  Route53 works for standard A, CNAME, etc, for any IP or domain on the internet.  Is your last sentence a typo and you are asking it's it's possible to alias (not CNAME) outside AWS?

Comment: Where in the API can I specify standard CNAME? AliasTarget stood out as the only reference to CNAME. Let me check again.

Comment: No idea, I use the console for that. Check the docs?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    Action: aws.String("CREATE"),
    ResourceRecordSet: &route53.ResourceRecordSet{
    Name: aws.String("mysite.com."),
    Type: aws.String("CNAME"),
    ResourceRecords: []*route53.ResourceRecord{
        {
            Value: aws.String("othersite.com"),
        },
    },
    TTL: aws.Int64(600),
    },
```